# Change Value in a list based on previous condition

Tags: python, list, numpy, enumerate

I have a list of zeros and ones.
I am trying to replace the a value of 1 with a 0 if the previous value is also a 1 for a desired output as shown below.

```
list =     [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]
new_list = [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0]
```

I've tried using a for loop to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried?

Comment: `y = np.copy(x);  y[1:] = y[1:] & ~y[:-1] `

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser - Excellent!  I was trying to work out a way to do this bitwise.  This should be the accepted answer.  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Thank You! This worked great and is probably the cleanest approach. For the sake of being difficult Lets say we wanted to keep the first two occurrences of 1 so the new output would be new_list = [1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]

Answer (score 2):

How about this for loop:

```
list =     [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]
new_list = []

ant=0
for i in list:
    if ant ==0 and i==1:
        new_list.append(1)
    else:
        new_list.append(0)
    ant=i
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
question_list = [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]
new_list = [question_list[0]] # notice we put the first element here
for i in range(1, len(question_list) + 1):
    # check if the current and previous element are 1
    if question_list[i] == 1 and question_list[i - 1] == 1:
        new_list.append(0)
    else:
        new_list.append(question_list[i])
```

The idea here is we iterate over the list, while checking the previous element.