# Set consecutive equal numbers in an array equal to zero

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I have an array like

```
a = np.array( [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1] )
```

and am looking for a way to set consecutive equal elements to zero:

```
a_desired =  np.array( [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] )
```

I've had a pretty unsuccessful time of it so far, I've tried something as simple as

```
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if a[i+1] == a[i]:
        a[i+1] = 0
```

with output `[1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1]`, as well as adding more conditions, like

```
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if a[i+1] == a[i]:
        a[i+1] = 0 
    if a[i+1] != a[i] and a[i] == 0 and a[i+1] != a[i]:
        a[i+1] = 0
```

which has output `[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`, but I can't seem to be able to successfully capture all the conditions required to make this work.

Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just a suggestion: don't modify an array that you are iterating over. Modify a copy and iterate over the original instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66323104/change-value-in-a-list-based-on-previous-condition/66323166#66323166 I hope this other question helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try：

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
a_desired = np.zeros(a.shape)

for i in range(len(a)-1, -1, -1):
    if a[i] == a[i-1] and i != 0:
        a_desired[i] = 0
    else:
        a_desired[i] = a[i]

print(a_desired)
```

Output:

```
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it following way:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
a[1:][a[:-1]==a[1:]] = 0
print(a)
```

output:

```
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]
```

I compare `a` without last element with `a` without first element, thus I do pair-wise comparison between what might be called *previous* element and *current* element, which result in array of `True`s and `False`s which is 1 shorther then `a`, then I use it as mask to set `0` where is `True`. Note that I only modify part of `a` after first element, as first will never change.

Comment: I also really like this one, although I don't fully understand it just yet. I'm sure it'll click soon enough though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try numpy `xor`

```py
np.insert((np.logical_xor(a[:-1], a[1:]) * a[1:]), 0, a[0])
```

```
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
value_detected = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if value_detected:
        if a[i] == value_detected:
            a[i] = 0
        else:
            value_detected = a[i]
    else:
        if a[i]:
            value_detected = a[i]

print(a)
```

For original input, the output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Further test, if input is:

```
a = [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Then output is:

```
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list with one element which would be the first element of input list.

Now, just iterate through your list starting from 2nd element and check if it is equal to the previous value.

If yes append 0 else, append the value.

```
input_arr = [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
output_arr = [input_arr[0]]
for i in range(1, len(input_arr)):
  if input_arr[i]==input_arr[i-1]:
    output_arr.append(0)
  else:
    output_arr.append(input_arr[i])


print (output_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

From me, first i make copy of original array and then make new desired array like this:

```
new_a = a.copy()
for i in range(1, len(a)):        
    if a[i] == a[i-1]: new_a[i] = 0
print(new_a)
```